# iterating through an output comparing data in same position for continuity

Tags: python, replace, row, multiple-columns

```
A.append([(float(a) + float(b) + float(c))/3,
    (float(d) + float(e) + float(f))/3,
    (float(g) + float(h) + float(i))/3,
    (float(j) + float(k) + float(l))/3,
    (float(m) + float(n) + float(o))/3,
    (float(p) + float(q) + float(r))/3,
    (float(s) + float(t) + float(u))/3])
```

gives me an output of 7 values displayed like so

```
[[-9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0], [-9999.0, -9999.0, -6665.9694239999999, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0], [0.040896999999999996, 0.018690666666666664, 0.016837666666666667, -9999.0, 0.038722666666666669, 0.018323666666666669, -9999.0], [0.039443666666666662, 0.017517666666666667, 0.013396, -9999.0, 0.035526333333333333, 0.011692666666666665, -9999.0], [-9999.0, 0.017963666666666666, 0.017425333333333334, -9999.0, 0.037885000000000002, 0.014316333333333334, -9999.0]]
```

I would like to go through these groups of 7 numbers down each column and check that the difference between two numbers is not greater then 0.03 and if it is replace the larger number with -9999.00.
I am unsure of how to compare the same elements from different rows, and if I need to replace one of the numbers how to go about doing it. i was thinking some sort of count to indicate row, but am very unsure how to go forward with this. I'm new to python so any help and patience is appreciated.

Comment: You have 21 1-letter variables and 21 calls to float. You should probably be using a list and some loops.

Comment: Use `numpy.avg([float(i) for i in ...])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested, but this should do it

```
rows = myListOfRows
for col in xrange(len(rows[0])):
    checkCol(rows, col)

def checkCol(rows, c):
    for r in xrange(len(rows)-1):
        if rows[r][c] != -9999 or -9999 != rows[r+1][c]: # checking for elements that are not already -9999.00
            if abs(rows[r][c] - rows[r+1][c]) > 0.03:
                rows[max([r,r+1], key=lambda rr: rows[rr][c])][c] = -9999.00
```

Comment: How could I add conditions to not check against the points that are already -9999.0? I think I have successfully added a condition that will skip if -9999.0 is the first number in the pair being compared but not if it is the second number in the pair.